# How to highlight div using javascript or jquery

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I spent about hour and did not find any clue how to highlight my div.

Ok example my code.

1.proccess.php

```
$_SESSION['msg']='<div class="success">Your account has been updated</div>';
header("location:http://domain.com/account.php/");
```

2.account.php

```
if ($_SESSION['msg']!="") {
echo $_SESSION['msg'];
unset($_SESSION['msg']);
}
```

Now I want the javascript or jquery to highlight the `<div class="success">` on account.php. How to do that? Let me know :)

Comment: Typically focus is for input objects …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[jQuery UI has a highlight effect](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.success').effect("highlight", {}, 3000);
});
```

The above code will need to be loaded into the page containing your div, along with jQuery, jQuery `ui.core.js` and `effects.highlight.js`

Comment: @bob - no problem, it sucks when you can't think of the correct search term, happens to all of us :)

Answer (score 1):

You probably were looking for this:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight

That's the highlight effect which "focusses" your attention. So "focus" was just the wrong search term to go for?